# ¿Cómo duplico una linea en WORD?

Tags: vb

En Visual Studio existe un shortcut "Ctrl + D" para duplicar una linea sin tener que hacer Ctrl + C Ctrl + V, ¿Cómo puedo hacer lo mismo en WORD?

Comment: En lugar de dejar un comentario, debes dejar una respuesta. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento. Recuerda que el formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_: los comentarios son solo para aclaraciones.

Comment: Pero no me deja responderme ami misma porque no tengo la puntuación adecuada

Comment: Al contrario: lo que no puedes es dejar comentarios en preguntas de otros por no tener suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges). Responder a tu propia pregunta por supuesto que es posible.

Answer (score 2):

Ah bueno nada, ya lo descubrí:se hace creando una macro

```
Sub DuplicateText() 
' Extiende la selección a toda la línea actual Selection.HomeKey 
     Unit:=wdLine Selection.EndKey 
     Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend 
' Copia    
     Selection.Copy 
     Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine 
     Selection.InsertParagraphAfter 
     Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1 
     Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting) 
End Sub –
```

Comment: Ahora acuérdate de marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así la pregunta no se quedará sin respuesta :) Creo que siendo tu propia respuesta te hará esperar 24h antes de poder aceptarla, pero se puede :)

Comment: Como se hace eso?